# Product of two permutations (cycles) in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic-programming

I would like to find the product of two permutations in Prolog (in cycle form) and I'm having problems with it (mostly because I can't even imagine, what it will look like).

I thought about changing these permutations into another representation, but I'm not sure which way is right.

So help me please, any hint is greatly appreciated.

> %permutationproduct(+P1,+P2,-Result)

**EDIT:** Under the product of permutation I mean this: [CLICK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Product_and_inverse) (but our inputs are in cycle notation, which makes the project more difficult). The inputs are 2 permutations (P1,P2) and the expected result is the 3rd parameter - the product of the permutations.

And I'm actually working on a bigger project, this is just one part of it, but as mentioned, I can't even start it, because I can't imagine it.

Comment: What is permutation product? What is the input? What is the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: Prolog's lists are ordered. So `[3,1,2,5,4]` makes a perfectly good representation of a permutation. You can look up Prolog predicates for dealing with lists. If you haven't read up on how Prolog works (via tutorial or book), then you'll need to. Your `permutation_product(P1, P2, Result)` could accept two such lists and result in a 3rd which is a product of the two. Is that a good enough to get you started? It should be simple. Give it a try and ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: I think it should be list of lists, since single permutation can be written as `(a,b,c)(d,e)`. The product in this case would be just a concatenation of the lists. But then some effort needed if one wants to have it in disjoint cycle form

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see. Yes, if the OP requires cycle form, then that's the way to do it. The flat list form makes `permutation_product/3` trivial (just used `nth1/3`). But without knowing more about context (*e.g.*, are the permutations originally in cycle form anyway? Do they need to be disjoint cycles? *etc.*), it's unclear which way would be best.

Comment: Yes, the original permutations are in disjoint cycles and so should the result be. But I'm not closer to the solution. Could you guys give me a more detailed explanation?

Comment: You have two choices for representation. Flat list (which I described already) or the cycles, which @EugeneSh. indicated you can also represent with lists. For example, the cycle, `(15)(24)` could be represented as `[[1,5],[2,4]]` in Prolog. Have you done any list processing in Prolog before?

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I've done list processing and I'm familiar with Prolog. I can write the recursion for the problem, I just don't know what do I have to write, since this is not just a concatenation.

Comment: Do you know how to convert from non-canonical cycle notation to  disjoint cycle form?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't.

Comment: Page 4 of [this document](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~jtmulhol/math302/notes/4-Permutations-CycleForm.pdf) is explaining it pretty well. From there it's just a matter of technique..